# JS in OOP approach - binding click action to a Div

Tags: javascript, oop

Im trying to add an action to a div which o just created,but i got some error on it,
i tried to use inspector in chrome and saw that the browser run `"$(ndiv2).click(function(){ this.dispose() });"` properly , the error occurs in the mouse click action

```
function gMessageBox(){
this.id=new Date().getTime();
this.boxId="div"+this.id;
this.boxTextId="txt"+this.id;
this.obj=null;
}
gMessageBox.prototype = {
    show: function(message){
        if(document.getElementById("div_messageshow")==null){
        var _body = parent.document.getElementsByTagName('body') [0];
        var ndiv=document.createElement("div");//Container
        var nspan=document.createElement("span")
        nspan.setAttribute("id", this.boxTextId );
        nspan.innerHTML=message;
        ndiv.setAttribute("id", this.boxId );
        var ndiv2=document.createElement("div");//close
        ndiv2.innerHTML="Close";
        ndiv2.setAttribute("style","float: right;cursor:pointer;");

        $(ndiv2).click(function(){ this.dispose() });

        ndiv.appendChild(nspan);
        ndiv.appendChild(ndiv2);
        _body.appendChild(ndiv);
        this.obj=ndiv;
                 }
    },
    dispose: function(){
        alert("dispose");
                    //do sth
    }
};


var mb=new gMessageBox();
mb.show("im message box");
```

Comment: Which error did you get?

Comment: In addition to what's the error, can you use jsfiddle.net to produce something that recreates the error?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'dispose'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `this` within the anonymous function you pass as a callback refers to that function's execution context and not to `gMessageBox` anymore. Either do

```
var that = this;
$(ndiv2).click(function(){ that.dispose(); });
```

or

```
$(ndiv2).click((function(){ this.dispose(); }).bind(this));
```